# Format disk in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, disk-utility

I remember using Disk Utility to format disks and USBs in 12.04.

Now, after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, I can't seem to find the Disk Utility application.

How do I format disks in 14.04?

Looking for applications that are installed by default to carry out this task

Comment: This is one more application the Gnome folks shredded. It is still there, but with reduced functionality and usability. I suggest you use GParted instead, this one they haven't touched yet.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Now it is named "Disks". Search for it in the Lens. (**command** `gnome-disks`)

[image]

And more options are as follows:

[image: screen]

Comment: Where can I partition the drive?

Comment: "Edit partition" or click the minus sign to remove the selected partition.